# Change a highchart x axis Label

Tags: php, highcharts, format

Is it possible to change the X axis labels of a highchart to include a thousand separator in the dot form?

My X axis has the following values 10000,20000,30000 I need to convert to 10.000,20.000,30.000

This is what I have:

```
$graph_EP->YaxisLabelFormat="{value}";
```

I need to change value to be shown with thousand separator. But I don't know how to manipulate value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set `thousandsSep`, like this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        thousandsSep: "."   
    }
});
```

Now, update your format:

```
format: '{value:,.0f}'
```

Working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/4bvhm97j/

More about formatting strings in Highcharts in the [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting).